# How to only SELECT data if a specific record is not exist

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to display multiple of data with a condition and skip rows if a specific record is exist in the same table in MySQL.

Here's example of the table

**table_a**

```
|      id     |     bi_id    |     status     |
|-------------|--------------|----------------|
|          1  |         111  |process1        |
|          2  |         112  |process1        |
|          3  |         112  |process2        |
|          4  |         113  |process1        |
|          5  |         111  |process2        |
|          6  |         111  |done            |
|          7  |         112  |done            |
```

I'm using this query below to select last id with status "done"

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_a WHERE status="done" GROUP BY bi_id
```

The struggle is where I want to display last id where the status is not "done" and dont select max id if bi_id with status "done" is exist, like this table below.

Expected result:

```
------------------
|    max(id)     |
|----------------|
|       4        |
```

My last try was using this query but as you know this is not gonna work. I also have tried query with NOT EXIST and not working either.

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM   table_a
WHERE status != "done" NOT IN
     (SELECT id
     FROM   table_a
     WHERE  status = "done" GROUP BY bi_id) GROUP BY by_id
```

Is there any workaround to achieve that with MySQL query or php/codeigniter?
Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: what errors do you face if any?
and what are your expected results?

Comment: I'm trying to get max id where status is not "done" and skip row if bi_id has "done" status. I've edited my quetion and add expected table result.

Comment: @MohammadFahadRao I face no errors, only the result is not what I expected. My expected result is to get the last id where bi_id not contain any "done" status.

Comment: try to get last inserted id as you execute the insert query and then use it with other condition

Comment: Why only `id=3` is selected? for `bi_id=112` the chain if ids is `2-3-7`, and last non-"done" is `3`, this is clear... but the same chain for `bi_id=111` is `1-5-6`, why `id=5` is not selected?

Comment: What if you have a data like this `(8,114,'process2'), (10,114,'process1')` in addition to your example above? I assume that since your query have `GROUP BY bi_id`, and adding these data, the result of `MAX(id)` will be two (`4,10`), correct?

Comment: @Akina Apologize, I've made a mistake, the result should return 4 as id `4` with bi_id '113' has no "done" in the status column.

Comment: @FaNo_FN Yes, excactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT MAX(`id`)
FROM `table_a`
WHERE `status` != 'done'
AND `bi_id` NOT IN (
  SELECT `t2`.`bi_id`
  FROM `table_a` AS `t2`
  WHERE `t2`.`status` = 'done'
);
```

In this way you exclude the rows with `bi_id` with `status = 'done'`.
You can see the result in this [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fHeuszX5ncJEVbcs9Y5iom/0).

Comment: Oooh that's it, and adding group by `bi_id` at the end of the query will do the works for me. Need to learn more I guess :/
Anyway thanks for the help sir, appriciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a query this simple:

```
SELECT MAX(id)
 FROM table_a
 GROUP BY bi_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(status) NOT LIKE '%done%'
```

In the query example above, I'm making use of the `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` function. Basically, what I'm doing with the query is:

```
SELECT bi_id, GROUP_CONCAT(status), MAX(id) 
 FROM table_a
 GROUP BY bi_id;
```

Which will return:

```
+-------+------------------------+---------+
| bi_id | GROUP_CONCAT(status)   | MAX(id) |
+-------+------------------------+---------+
| 111   | process1,process2,done |    6    |
| 112   | process1,process2,done |    7    |
| 113   | process1               |    4    |
| 114   | process2,process1      |   10    |
+--------------------------------+---------+
```

As you can see, the `bi_id` for both `111 & 112` have result of `GROUP_CONCAT(status)` inclusive of `done` in it. Therefore, these two are filtered out during the query `HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(status) LIKE '%done%'`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4bb9e50d6da9016d18191678705839c2)

P/S: Taking consideration of the last comment, I've added two additional rows in the example `(8,114,'process2'), (10,114,'process1')`.